# Error in JAXB unMarshaller?

Tags: java, jaxb

i am getting the following while reading from my .xml file.here is the error

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.dJohn.com/teacher", local:"teacher"). Expected elements are (none)
```

And here is my file.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Teacher xmlns="http://www.dJohn.com/teacher" Id="0001" />
```

main class

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class convertorDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

     try {

        File file = new File("C:\\file.xml");
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Teacher.class);

        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        Teacher mrS= (Teacher ) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);


      } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
     }

}
```

and here is Teacher.java..leaving some other details

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;



@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Teacher", propOrder = {       
})
public class Teacher{

   @XmlAttribute(name = "Id")
    protected String Id;


    public String getId() {
        return Id;
    }


    public void setId(String value) {
        this.Id = value;
    }  

}
```

I don't know what my problem is and i am new to JAXB.please help!!

Comment: add `Tana.class` to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotate your `Tana` class with `XmlRootElement`.